# Who was the first Pope?

Tags: ancient-history, christianity, catholic-church

I know that Peter is the first Pope, but I do believe that he is called a bishop and is one of several including the Bishops of Constantinople, Jerusalem, Alexandria, and others. Who was the first Pope to call himself by that name? Was it Leo who increased Papal power or someone else?

Comment: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pope#Title_and_etymology) says "The earliest record of the use of this title was in regard to the by then deceased Patriarch of Alexandria, Pope Heraclas of Alexandria (232–248).[24] The earliest recorded use of the title "pope" in English dates to the mid-10th century, when it was used in reference to Pope Vitalian in an Old English translation of Bede's Historia ecclesiastica gentis Anglorum.[25]"

Comment: Actually, Pope is just "Father", so it was "a normal title" for christian priests long time ago. Even now still there are **two** Popes: of Rome and of Alexandria.

Comment: It's *papa*, not *pater*, the actual Latin word for "father." It isn't quite "daddy" either, as that was *tata*. It was a word used for a father, though, similar to English's own "papa" or "pop".

Comment: This question is not clear. You need to state whether "pater" or "papa" or "il papa" is the word in question. You also need to state whether the person is ascribed to having written that himself, or whether others have written something calling him that.

Comment: Maybe the question should be reworded as "Who was the first bishop of Rome to claim supremacy over all other bishops?"

Comment: The question is perfectly intelligible as it stands.

Comment: [Is the Pope even Catholic?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RMf4OtC7SXY)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first title to be used for "pope" properly was the Latin *Pontifex Maximus*, which was originally the title for the chief of the College of Priests (*Collegium Pontificum*), sort of religious priests of the city of Rome itself.

By the time Christianity came around, the Pontifex Maximus of Rome was the emperor. That changed with [Gratian](https://books.google.com/books?id=vmsPAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA122&dq=pontifex+maximus+gratian&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAWoVChMIzeDEmfvjyAIVBWw-Ch2IQAFn#v=onepage&q=pontifex%20maximus%20gratian&f=false) who renounced it. Later, Leo I (as you guessed) resumed the title.

Papa (Gk. πάππας, "pappas") from which comes the English pope, was applied to senior priests, but seems to have been applied to the chief of Christian bishops only with [Pope Heraclas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pope_Heraclas_of_Alexandria), if Wikipedia is to be believed.

Answer (score 1):

There is a disagreement between different authorities. Some consider [Clement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pope_Clement_I) to be the first legitimate successor of Peter the Apostle and the first Bishop of Rome after him. The Catholic Church itself considers Clement to be the first pope after Peter. The reason for this is that the [Liber Pontificalis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liber_Pontificalis), the official book on the popes of the Church, specifically says that Peter chose Clement to be his *successor*. Other authorities consider [Linus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pope_Linus) to have been the first pope after Peter..

Comment: According to the official Catholic list the first four popes are (1) Peter, (2) Linus, (3) Anacletus, (4) Clement.

Comment: @TylerDurden If all the bishops of the time called themselves something like Pope, how could the power of the Pope as head of the church exist? It sounds like all the Bishops were equal. When was it established and practiced that the Bishop of Rome would be the head of all Christendom?

Comment: it is rather silly to ask who was the first person to used a title translated into English as pope.  The question should  rather be which alleged successor of St. Peter first called himself Bishop of Jerusalem and which first called himself bishop of Rome; then which alleged successor first called himself Archbishop or Metropolitan of Jerusalem & the same for Rome, the first to call himself Primate of Italy, the first to call himself Patriarch, and the first Bishop of Rome to claim to rule the whole Christian church.